# Wordpress and Anythingslider Navigation Thumbnails

Tags: jquery, wordpress, anythingslider

So I am using AnythingSlider in Wordpress. This is why I am trying to call the thumbnails from the original posts. Anything slider will configure thumbnail navigation like this:

```
function formatText(index, panel) {
  return index + "";
}

$(function () {

    $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider({
        navigationFormatter: formatText       // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
    });

});
```

As you can see, the navigationFormatter will allow me to format the nav (including thumbnails) however I want. For example, to format thumbnails, I could do this:

```
 navigationFormatter : function(i, panel){ // add thumbnails as navigation links
return '<img src="images/th-slide-' + ['civil-1', 'env-1', 'civil-2', 'env-2'][i - 1] + '.jpg">';
```

}
So my issue is getting the wordpress slide images to show up there dynamically, rather than in a folder (as the above example shows). For reference, this is my php query that is pulling the posts image (from a script I've already written:

```
    <img class="slider-img" style="float:left;" src="<?php if(function_exists('wp_get_post_image')){ echo wp_get_post_image(array( 'return_html' => false, 'width' => 500 )); } ?>" />
```

I hope this update helps. Thank you guys so much. The Stack overflow community is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same loop that is setting your anythingSlider content's `LI` to set a JS array and then echo it before your jQuery calls or using something like:

```
$thumbArrStr = "[";
foreach($yourThumbData as $k=>$v) {
    $thumbArrStr .= "'$v',";
}
$thumbArrStr = substr($thumbArrStr, 0, -1);
$thumbArrStr .= "]";
echo "var anythingSliderArr = $thumbArrStr;";
```

And now use `anythingSliderArr`:

```
navigationFormatter : function(i, panel){ // add thumbnails as navigation links
    return '<img src="images/th-slide-' + anythingSliderArr[i - 1] + '.jpg">';
}
```

Comment: The issue is the img src is still pointing to images/th-slide - which does not exist. I need to be able to use a WP function in there to get the post image.

Comment: I didn't really get you, but aren't you looping these posts? so you can have the thumbnail and store them in a PHP var and then echo it in the JS array var.

Comment: Hey,
Where do I need to write the code??
I don't know how I tell the javascript function the URL of my WP Thumbnails

I created a custom post type and have a loop for creating the slider. I have to save my post-thumbnails into an array and give it to the navigationformatter function.. but how??

Comment: @Ben: this php code can be put anywhere *above* the `anythingslider` initialization